# Efficient and reliable ways to solve the equation $Y_m(ka)J_m(kb)-J_m(ka)Y_m(kb)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, bessel-functions, eigenfunctions, cylindrical-coordinates

The answers to the question [Bessel Functions Sturm-Liouville problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463959/bessel-functions-sturm-liouville-problem) show that the eigenfunctions of the Helmholtz equation
$$
(-\nabla^2+k^2)\psi(\mathbf r)=0
$$
in an annulus $a<r<b$, that have cylindrical separability of the form $\psi(r,\theta) = f(r)e^{im\theta}$ and which are subject to hard Dirichlet boundary conditions at both an inner and an outer ring,
$$
f(a)=f(b)=0,
$$
are linear combinations of Bessel functions of the first and second kinds, of the form
$$
f(r) = N\bigg[Y_m(ka)J_m(kr)-J_m(ka)Y_m(kr)\bigg],
$$
where the (square root of the) eigenvalue $k$ is fixed by requiring that the eigenfunction vanish at the outer ring:
$$
f(b)/N=
Y_m(ka)J_m(kb)-J_m(ka)Y_m(kb)=0
\tag{$*$}
$$

**I am looking for efficient and reliable ways to solve this equation**, i.e. given $m$ and $b/a$, find the $k$ that corresponds to the eigenvalue.

For the circular problems, the zeroes of both $J_m(kr)$ and $Y_m(kr)$ are widely tabulated ([example](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21)) and are often available as standard parts of scientific software packages ([example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html)), but the annular case isn't nearly as well-established. What are good ways to numerically solve that equation and *reliably* come up with the correct roots?

Comment: Ah. As often happens, once this post was mostly written, I found the [relevant section in the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21#x); the asymptotics can then be used as initial seeds for a Newton's-method solver, providing sufficient reliability in finding the correct root for a large range of values of $b/a$, $m$ and the root order. I'll leave this up for anybody who wants to write it up and in case it's useful for someone else down the line.

Comment: Hmmm. Upon a closer look, that's not quite enough. If someone has a reliable solver for getting the first few roots at highish $m$, say 5 or so, at $b/a \gtrsim 5€, that'd be mighty interesting.

Comment: It may be useful to know that BesselJZero inverts $\frac{J_m(x)}{Y_m(x)}$, but your equation is still tedious to solve with it